# Custom keyboard interrupt handler. Assembly. 8086

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, real-mode, keyboardinterrupt

I'm writting a resident program which patches in keyboard interrupt handler, and on each key stroke searches a word in video memory. When the word is found, it will write a line with this word in a file. I call old interrupt handler in my new handler, but when I run the program in DOSBox, keyboard doesn't work. I think that problem is that I make DOS interrupts in my interrupt, but I'm not sure. I've tested the non-resident part of the program and also handler function when it was just a function. So the code below doesn't conation section for commandline parsing and error handling.

```
     .model tiny
    .code   
    org 100h              
    jmp start
start_resident:    
new_int9 proc far                   ;must be far + iret  
    pushf 
    call cs:old_int9
    pusha          
    push ds
    push es
    push cs
    pop ds
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax         
    cld                       
    mov bx, -2d
    mov si, [bx]
    lea di, parameters
    ;si is used for locating video buffer
    ;di is used for locating pattern
    page_iteration:        
        add bx, 2d
        cmp bx, 16d                        ;16 = 2 * 8 is number of pages       
        je findPattern_exit
        mov si, video_pages[bx]
        lea di, parameters       
        cmp_str_iteration:
            mov ax, video_pages[bx + 2]              ;check pages' intervals
            cmp si, ax
            je page_iteration
            mov ax, es:[si]
            mov ah, ds:[di]
            add si, 2
            inc di
            ;equ
            cmp ah, al
            je cmp_str_iteration
            ;nequ
            mov ax, di          ;ax holds fst not equ char
            lea di, parameters
            sub ax, di 
            cmp ax, n
            jnz cmp_str_iteration
            ;equ_words
            mov video_offset, si
            mov ax, bx         
            cwd
            div two
            mov npage, ax                                                     
            add al, '0'                         
            mov file_name[1], al    ;al - page number 

            mov ah, 3dh             ;open a file 
            mov al, 1               ;write only
            lea dx, file_name
            int 21h            
            jc create_and_open_file
            mov fd, ax

            mov ah, 42h
            mov al, 2
            mov bx, fd
            mov cx, 0               ;upper portion of offset
            mov dx, 0               ;lower portion of offset      
            int 21h
            mov errno, 2
            jc findPattern_error
            mov errno, -1
            jmp write_file
        create_and_open_file:
            mov ah, 3ch
            mov cx, 0
            lea dx, file_name
            int 21h                
            mov errno, 1                
            jc findPattern_error    ;pop from stack ret?
            mov errno, -1
            mov fd, ax       
        write_file:
            mov bx, npage
            mov ax, video_pages[bx]     ;ax holds current video page offset
            mov bx, video_offset
            sub bx, ax                  ;[0..24][0..80]
            mov ax, bx
            cwd
            div row_size                ;ax holds column
            cwd
            mul row_size                ;bottom round 
            mov bx, npage
            add ax, video_pages[bx]     ;ax holds address of current column

            mov dx, ax

            mov ah, 40h
            mov bx, fd
            mov cx, 160d
            push ds
            push es
            pop ds          ;ds - b800h
            int 21h 
            mov errno, 3        
            jc findPattern_error    ;write error
            mov errno, -1
            pop ds                    
            mov ah, 3eh
            mov bx, fd      ;close file
            int 21h                    

            mov bx, npage            
            jmp cmp_str_iteration 
findPattern_error:      
findPattern_exit:       
    pop es
    pop ds
    popa
    iret
new_int9 endp     

    cmd_length db 0

    execErr db "Can't execute Can't specified program execute Can't execute Can't specified program execute", 10,13,'$' 
    errno   dw 0                          
    errLen  db 27
    errorStr db "Invalid usage.",10,13,"$$$$$$$$$$$"         
             db "Create file error.",10,13,"$$$$$$$"  
             db "Move file pointer error.",10,13,'$'
             db "Write error.",10,13,"$$$$$$$$$$$$$"
    ;variables used to parse commandline
    ibord dw 0
    borders dw 3 dup(0)
    left equ 0
    right equ 2    
    iparam dw -1
    parameters db 256 dup(0)  
    pos dw 0                  
    n   dw 0
    nstr equ 128               
    fisrt equ 0
    second equ 128          

    old_int9 dd 0  

    file_name db "FX.TXT", 0    
    fd dw 0                

    video_pages dw 0h, 1000h, 2000h, 3000h, 4000h, 5000h, 6000h, 7000h, 8000h
    video_offset dw 0
    npage  dw 0 

    com_tail_size db 0
    com_tail db 127 dup(0Dh)             

    two dw 2d
    row_size dw 160d
start:              
    ;code to parse command line
jmp install_handler                        
install_handler:
    mov ah, 35h         
    mov al, 09h  
    int 21h
    mov word ptr old_int9, bx
    mov word ptr old_int9 + 2, es

    mov ah, 25h
    mov al, 09h               
    mov dx, offset new_int9
    int 21h                

    mov ax, 3100h
    mov dx, (start - start_resident + 10Fh) / 16
    int 21h                                
end start
```

So, please, tell me what is wrong with my keyboard interrupt handler?

Comment: Remove everything except calling the old handler. Does it work then? Also note some code paths unbalance the stack.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Fix that trivial case (doing nothing but calling the original interrupt handler) first.  If that doesn't work, then nothing else will.  You cannot call any of the DOS interrupt functions from your interrupt handler.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : It is possible to use DOS routines from an interrupt if the InDOS flag isn't set. Some DOS functions can be called from an interrupt handler (Int 0x21 subfunctions 0x01 to 0x0C) when InDOS flag is set. In this case doing file I/O without seeing if the InDOS flag has been set is asking for trouble.

Comment: I'd be very curious to know which assembler and linker you are using to generate this COM program and what options you pass to the assembler and linker.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Explain how it fails. No keyboard input? sluggish response? Describe how it fails.

Comment: It is also unclear where `parameters` and `n` gets filled in. The code to parse a command line seems to be missing and those variables are uninitialized.

Comment: Regarding using DOS interrupts in an interrupt handler Ross Ridge's answer may be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584477/… . Ross provides a good link to the type of solutions you could consider to work around this: http://phatcode.net/res/223/files/html/Chapter_18/CH18-3.html from the book Art of Assembly. I don't believe that is the primary problem in this code though (although it is a significant bug)

Comment: Early x86 PCs (IBM PC, PCjr, XT, AT, Tandy ...) used different types of keyboard circuits that required different interrupt handlers. There were even PCs that did not use IRQ #1: PCjr used the NMI instead. If DOSBox only claims to emulate some MS-DOS compatible PC, but not to emulate an AT-compatible system, it is neither guaranteed that IRQ #1 is executed, nor that accesses to I/O ports 60h-63h work.

Comment: By the way: Calling OS (`int 21h`) or BIOS functions from an interrupt handler is not a good idea. This can crash the (emulated) computer!

Comment: @MartinRosenau DOSBox emulates a 386 processor, supports (emulates) PS/2 controller ports 0x60 and port 0x64. It also emulates keyboard interrupts on IRQ1. As I pointed out previously calling Int 21h in certain cases is a problem from an interrupt handler (because most DOS Int 21h calls aren't re-entrant) but there are ways around it. The primary problem here is that neither `n` or `parameters` are initialized. When I manually set them to a string to search for it worked. It slows down keyboard input considerably especially when the target string is matched.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was compiling the program with emu8086, and then I was running it in DOSBox. The program worked as I expected it to work, when I compiled it with tasm and .386 directive. The variables are not initialized, because I tested the code for finding a word and parsing a commandline and it seemed to work, so I didn't include it in my question.